# Using getAuthPassword() with another Model instead of User Model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am facing issue, I want to use different field name for password. let us say in users table, when I use this code with User model it works perfectly

```
/**
 * Override required, otherwise existing Authentication system will not match credentials
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->userPassword;
}
```

but when I use it with another Model let us say Customer model with same table structure , it doesnt work??!!! does anyone have idea about this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your config folder there is a file "auth.php" in this file you found authentication driver set to `'model' => 'App\User'` 
Instead of User you can use any of your model.
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: My issue is why is not override that actual getAuthPassword() when I use it with another Model for example Customer model ? by the way the structure of Customer Model is same as User Model

Comment: for that you need to use `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;` in your customer model